# Is adb tool is used for security testing?

Tags: android, android-emulator, security-testing

Is adb tool is used for security testing?

Hi All,
        Is adb tool is used for security testing of mobile applications?
can any one help me out and is it possible to run on ubuntu?

Comment: Have you checkout this ? [Pentest on Android app](https://gbhackers.com/android-application-penetration-test-part-1/), 2nd and 3rd parts are on ADB tool

Answer (score -1):

Yes ADB(Android Debug Bridge) tool can be used for Android Mobile app security Testing.ADB comes along with android sdk(software development toolkit) , so it's possible to run on ubuntu platform by downloading android sdk.

Android Debug Bridge (adb) is a command line tool that lets you communicate with an emulator or connected Android device.Some of the usefull commands are as follows :

- adb devices : displays list of all attached devices/emulators.
- adb help : displays list of supported adb commands.

Reference link : Click [Here](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781849515603/9/ch09lvl1sec57/security-testing-the-resources)